# Trying to develop a new extension method

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, lambda

I'm using the Entity Framework and I developed this extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<TResult> Like<TResult>(this IQueryable<TResult> query, Expression<Func<TResult, string>> field, string value) 
{
    var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TResult, bool>>(
        Expression.Call(field.Body, typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"),
        Expression.Constant(value)), field.Parameters);

    return query.Where(expression);
}
```

this code work correctly if I use it like this:

```
var result = from e in context.es.Like(r => r.Field, "xxx")
             select e
```

Now I need to call this extension method programmatically:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> SearchInText<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, string textToFind)
{
    // Collect fields
    PropertyInfo[] propertiesInfo = source.ElementType.GetProperties();
    List<string> fields = new List<string>();
    foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertiesInfo)
    {
        if (
            (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(string)) ||
            (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(int)) ||
            (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(long)) ||
            (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(byte)) ||
            (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(short))
            )
        {
            fields.Add(propertyInfo.Name);
        }
    }

    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), source.ElementType.Name);
    Expression expression = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(parameter, typeof(TSource).GetProperty(fields[0])), parameter);
    Expression<Func<TSource, string>> field = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, string>>(expression, parameter);

    return source.Like(field, textToFind);
}
```

Now this code doesn't work!
I need to understand how to declare the "field" of the Like extended methods.

```
Expression<Func<TSource, string>> field = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, string>>(expression, parameter);
```

At runtime I receive this error: Impossibile utilizzare un'espressione di tipo 'System.Func`2[TestMdf.Equipment,System.String]' per un tipo restituito 'System.String'

Comment: I'm a little confused by your second extension method. You loop through all the PropertyInfo on the element, add them to a collection of fields, then just pick the first one. This seems really vague and untargeted...very likely to return random results. Before I provide any kind of answer...is that what you want? Or do you really need to pick a specific property to search for...or do you need to loop through all properties and call .Like() for each one and aggregate the results?

Comment: Hi,
you are right about the loop...
The final version of this extended methods will generate several where clause.

In example, you have fields F1, F2, F3 that are numbers or strings
I'd like to search in text like this:
' ' + F1 + ' ' + F2 + ' ' + F3 + ' ' LIKE '%<textToFind>%'

But will be more complicated again...
I'd like to add a little search engine so:
' ' + F1 + ' ' + F2 + ' ' + F3 + ' ' LIKE '%<word1>%'
AND ' ' + F1 + ' ' + F2 + ' ' + F3 + ' ' LIKE '%<word2>%'
AND ' ' + F1 + ' ' + F2 + ' ' + F3 + ' ' NOT LIKE '%<word3>%'
and manage phrases too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my first release:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> SearchInText<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, string textToFind)
{
    if (textToFind.Trim() == "")
    {
        return source;
    }
    string[] textToFindList = textToFind.Replace("'", "''").Split(' ');

    // Collect fields
    PropertyInfo[] propertiesInfo = source.ElementType.GetProperties();
    List<string> fieldList = new List<string>();
    foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertiesInfo)
    {
        if (
            (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(string)) ||
            (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(int)) ||
            (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(long)) ||
            (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(byte)) ||
            (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(short))
            )
        {
            fieldList.Add(propertyInfo.Name);
        }
    }

    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), source.ElementType.Name);
    MethodInfo concatMethod = typeof(String).GetMethod("Concat", new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) });

    var spaceExpression = Expression.Constant(" ");
    var concatenatedField = BinaryExpression.Add(spaceExpression, Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, typeof(TSource).GetProperty(fieldList[0])), concatMethod);

    for (int i = 1; i < fieldList.Count; i++)
    {
        concatenatedField = BinaryExpression.Add(concatenatedField, spaceExpression, concatMethod);
        concatenatedField = BinaryExpression.Add(concatenatedField, Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, typeof(TSource).GetProperty(fieldList[i])), concatMethod);
    }

    concatenatedField = BinaryExpression.Add(concatenatedField, spaceExpression, concatMethod);
    var fieldsExpression = Expression.Call(concatenatedField, "ToUpper", null, null);

    var clauseExpression = Expression.Call(
        fieldsExpression, typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new Type[] { typeof(string) }),
        Expression.Constant(textToFindList[0].ToUpper())
        );

    if (textToFindList.Length == 1)
    {
       return source.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(clauseExpression, parameter));
    }

    BinaryExpression expression = Expression.And(Expression.Call(
            fieldsExpression, typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new Type[] { typeof(string) }),
            Expression.Constant(textToFindList[1].ToUpper())
            ), clauseExpression);
    for (int i = 2; i < textToFindList.Length; i++)
    {
        expression = Expression.And(Expression.Call(
            fieldsExpression, typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new Type[] { typeof(string) }),
            Expression.Constant(textToFindList[i].ToUpper())
            ), expression);
    }

    return source.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(expression, parameter));

}
```

I will modify to manage some rules like "phrase" + and - operator.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your second code snippet is just a truncated example - if you really did that, then the results would be unpredictable, because you're taking the first property returned by reflection, which can change between runs of your program.

You'll get better answers if you say "This worked" followed by a description of what happened, and "This didn't work" followed by a description of how you could tell that it didn't work (compiler error? runtime error? exception message?)

Firstly, are you aware of [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)? It allows you to delay decisions about how a query should be structured until runtime and may solve many of your problems for you.

But assuming this is a learning exercise...

Your `Like` extension method takes an expression (which a caller ought to usually write out as a lambda, as that's the whole point of these things). That expression will convert a "record" from a query result set and return a string value (presumably selecting it from the data stored in the record). The method also takes a value string.

But it then constructs (by hand) its own predicate that calls the `Contains` method on the body of the `field` lambda.

I guess this ought to work, because the result of that lambda is a string. However, I can't see why you're doing this the hard way. What's wrong with:

```
var result = from e in context.es
             where e.Field.Contains("xxx"))
             select e
```

Comment: Hi, I'd like to search in all fields so you have to compose the fields like this ' ' + F1 + ' ' + F2 ... 
I need an extended methods just because I don't know the field list.
You are right, my second code snippet is just a truncated example.
I think that this extended method can be very useful so I hope I can found some help to complete it.

Comment: My first extended methods is the only way that I found to call dinamically the Contains methods.
I need to call it dinamically because I have to build the field to compare. Something like (" " + F1 + " " + F2 + " ").Contains(" " + <word1> + " ")

Comment: I need to understand how I have to build the parameter to call the Like method.
If you write in your code field.Like("text") this is simple. But I don't know how I can call it dinamically.
About the "doesn't work": it compiles but I recieve this error on runtime: "Impossibile utilizzare un'espressione di tipo 'System.Func`2[TestMdf.Equipment,System.String]' per un tipo restituito 'System.String'"

Answer (score 0):

Now I found a partial solution to my problem:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> SearchInText<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, string textToFind)
{
    // Collect fields
    PropertyInfo[] propertiesInfo = source.ElementType.GetProperties();
    List<string> fields = new List<string>();
    foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertiesInfo)
    {
        if (
            (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(string)) ||
            (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(int)) ||
            (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(long)) ||
            (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(byte)) ||
            (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(short))
            )
        {
            fields.Add(propertyInfo.Name);
        }
    }

    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource),     source.ElementType.Name);

    var property = typeof(TSource).GetProperty(fields[0]);
    var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
        var constantValue = Expression.Constant(textToFind);
    var equality = Expression.Call(Expression.Call(Expression.Property(parameter,     property), "ToUpper", null, null), typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new Type[] { typeof(string) }), Expression.Constant(textToFind.ToUpper()));

    return source.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(equality, parameter));
}
```

Now the next step is to concatenate all the field list:

```
" " + fields[0] + " " + ... fields[n]
```

Some ideas?

Comment: Field concatenation?  You probably want to use a StringBuilder.