# linq to entities expression tree where on anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to create a filter to search on one or more columns on the base query. It works, the problem is that I am 100% sure that it is not optimal since the query is rendered and the search is performed via code (not by MSSQL)

So my question is: can I do this via Expression tree (not familiar with it) so the query is generated the the db side ?

p.s: I don't want to use Dynamic LINQ

Thank you!

```
 var basequery = (from x in db.table1
                             join x1 in db.table2 on x.id equals x1.someid
                             where x.deleted != null && x.moreCondition = "blah"
                             select new {
                                 x.field1,
                                 x.fiedl2
                                 x2.field1,
                                 x2.field3
                             });
```

apply filter on base query to search each columns:

```
foreach (var item in Columns)
{

     basequery = basequery.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(i => (i.GetType().GetProperty(item.Data)
        .GetValue(i, null) ?? string.Empty).ToString().ToUpper().Contains(item.Search.Value.ToUpper())).AsQueryable();
}
```

Comment: This is what i need: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931444/trying-to-develop-a-new-extension-method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931444/trying-to-develop-a-new-extension-method)

Answer (score 1):

You need to build your expression tree combining filter predicates based on the list of Columns. But instead of doing it like you presented, you need to build filter expression which won't be materialized until one of materialisation method is used.

Here you have a nice example how to use Expression Trees to Build Dynamic Queries: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654267.aspx

And if you want to get some ready-made solution, just try a PredicateBuilder like described here:
http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx